Event polling with event.get() returning result with exception set
Resolution: I've been in conversation with an active pygame developer who, after running through my issue, has confirmed that a recent update to pygame has caused this issue. Again, none of the suggested threads in the blue message box that appears for me when I load this stack overflow page (telling me why my question is bad/redundant/etc.) are remotely relevant to an issue that has to do with the pygame engine having an internal issue.
I'm implementing audio in a pygame project. I've encountered an issue during an event loop.
I've drilled the code down to the bare minimum and it seems that defining and playing a sound via pygame.mixer.Sound and play() is creating an event that causes problems.
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

rain_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("testSound.mp3")
rain_sound.play(-1)

def safe_event_get():
    try:
        return pygame.event.get()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting events: {e}")
        return []

while True:
    for event in safe_event_get():
        pass

When I run this, the program runs and plays the audio correctly. But in the console, I see:
Error getting events: <built-in function get> returned a result with an exception set

I'm not unable to play audio. I'm unable to avoid my program crashing due to a problem with the event. This is a strange issue that so far seems to be environmental or due to some update to pygame that may have broken the mixer.

Try to use a different audio format. I don't suggest using an mp3 file type with the pygame mixer module. Try using .OGG instead.

I appreciate the tip. But I've been using mixer for quite a few projects and have been using a mixture of wavs and mp3's and haven't run into this issue before. I've literally had people tell me that this seems to be an underlying issue with pygame's event system which seems unreasonable to me since this is such a simple case

I just tested it with an OGG and there was no event error. Is pygame's mixer no longer good with mp3's?

Also past projects where I've used the mixer and mp 3's (as recently as a few months ago) suddenly all give this error and crash immediately. Did something change with python or pygame that broke mp3's? or at least broke the events associated with the playback of mp3's? (since mp3's still play but when polling the associated event you get a crash)

Mixer is a pygame module. I'm almost certain an update to pygame caused the issue you were experiencing. I'm glad I was of some assistance!
